# Apply the latest runtime updates to improve QnA Maker results - re-migrations required?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

We received an e-mail today from Microsoft with "recommended actions" regarding the QnA Maker runtime upgrade.

> Apply the latest runtime updates to improve QnA Maker results
>
> You’re receiving this email because you currently use the generally available
> Cognitive Services QnA Maker service. We’ve made some important
> runtime updates that will **require you to re-migrate from the free
> preview version**. These updates will improve the quality of results
> from the QnA Maker service. Recommended action To benefit from the
> updates, we recommend that you follow these steps:
>
> 1. Upgrade the QnA Maker runtime as [documented](https://azure.microsoft.com/email/?destination=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fcognitive-services%2Fqnamaker%2Fhow-to%2Ftroubleshooting-runtime%23how-to-get-latest-qnamaker-runtime-updates&p=bXNnSWQ9NjBjYTI2MzgtOTRjYS00MGIyLWJjZGUtZTYyMWMzMmFhOTc2JmpvYklkPTE2OWE4M2ZiLTQzMTEtNDM2My05YzhmLTc4NTljZTYxZjMzMSZzdWJzY3JpcHRpb25JZD01OTAwMzczZC0yNDE1LTQ4ZDAtOWU0Yy0zN2VlYzk4MjQxOGEmZW1haWxJZD1TZXJ2aWNlTm90aWZpY2F0aW9ucy9VcGdyYWRlUW5BTWFrZXJSdW50aW1lJmV2dElkPXNlcnZpY2Utbm90aWZpY2F0aW9uLXVwZ3JhZGUtcW5hLW1ha2VyLXJ1bnRpbWUmbGlua05hbWU9dHJvdWJsZXNob290aW5nLXJ1bnRpbWUmc291cmNlPWFlbw==).
> 2. ***If you have migrated a knowledge base from the free preview, please re-migrate by following [these steps](https://azure.microsoft.com/email/?destination=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fcognitive-services%2Fqnamaker%2Ftutorials%2Fmigrate-knowledge-base&p=bXNnSWQ9NjBjYTI2MzgtOTRjYS00MGIyLWJjZGUtZTYyMWMzMmFhOTc2JmpvYklkPTE2OWE4M2ZiLTQzMTEtNDM2My05YzhmLTc4NTljZTYxZjMzMSZzdWJzY3JpcHRpb25JZD01OTAwMzczZC0yNDE1LTQ4ZDAtOWU0Yy0zN2VlYzk4MjQxOGEmZW1haWxJZD1TZXJ2aWNlTm90aWZpY2F0aW9ucy9VcGdyYWRlUW5BTWFrZXJSdW50aW1lJmV2dElkPXNlcnZpY2Utbm90aWZpY2F0aW9uLXVwZ3JhZGUtcW5hLW1ha2VyLXJ1bnRpbWUmbGlua05hbWU9bWlncmF0ZS1rbm93bGVkZ2UtYmFzZSZzb3VyY2U9YWVv).***

When the QnA Maker service became generally available, we migrated from the preview version to the GA version. Since then, we heavily edited our knowledge base(s), therefore it has far more content than the version from the preview version.

The recommended action now states that we have to re-migrate our knowledge base(s) from the preview portal, which would make our recent changes in the QnA Maker service unusable.

Does anybody know the background of these recommended actions? Or is there any way to "upgrade" the QnA Maker knowledge base(s) without re-migratring from preview version?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is just a runtime update, all you need to do is restart the App Service as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/how-to/troubleshooting-runtime#how-to-get-latest-qnamaker-runtime-updates) referenced in the email you received and that is it, you don't need to worry about the preview stack anymore as Microsoft is encouraging everyone to migrate to and test the new GA stack as early as possible before the preview stack is no longer sustained.